# Good practice to avoid ConcurrentModification of static collection

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

Consider class of Player... when player joins the game (object is created), it checks for player with the same name already joined...

```
public class Player {

    private static List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;

        for (Player otherPlayer : players) { // Iterating static field
            if (otherPlayer.name.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                otherPlayer.quit("Somebody with the same name joined the game");
            }
        }
    }

    public void quit(String message) {
        players.remove(this); // Modifying static field
        Server.disconnect(this, message);
    }
}
```

I know that Iterator can deal with this problem, but we don't always know what happens with public static fields in foreign methods and when to use foreach and when to use Iterator instead...

Is there any good practice for this problem?

Comment: I wouldn't let a `Player` have a reference to all the players. It's not a player's responsibility to know all other players in the game. Encapsulate the list somewhere else and you can control the access and prevent any outsiders from doing things with it.

Comment: You create a separate class for the player list, and it maintains a tight grip on it, without anyone else able to modify it. There will be no "public static field" that anyone can change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first, and more important good practice is called **separation of concerns**. As in: the Player class should model a single **player**.

You are **mixing** the responsibility of being a Player and **managing** the overall set of Player objects in one place. Don't do that!

These two things simply don't belong together. In that sense: there should be a `PlayerManager` class for example that *knows* about all players. And also forget about using a `static` field like this. Because that creates super-tight coupling between the different aspects of your class. What happens for example when you need *more than one* list of players? What if you have so many players that you want to organize them in buckets, based on certain properties?

Beyond that, the direct answer is: instead of **immediately** deleting objects from your list - collect them into a second `playersToBeDeleted` list. And **after** iterating the first list, simply use `players.removeAll(playersToBeDeleted)` for example.

And talking about good practices: carefully consider if you really want to use **Lists** - or if **Set** wouldn't be the better alternative. Lists always imply order, and yuck, they allow to repeatedly add the *same* object. Whereas a Set gives you "unique elements" semantics for free!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to call `list.remove(entry)` method while still inside the for-each block. Don't do that.

Use `Iterator` instead of the for-each construct when you need to:

1. Remove the current element. The for-each construct hides the iterator, so you cannot call remove. Therefore, the for-each construct is not usable for filtering.
2. Iterate over multiple collections in parallel.

Note that `Iterator.remove` is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in progress.